# Messed up titlebars

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, titlebar

Noticed that yesterday there were some kind of updates, briefly ran through the list and remember keywords like OpenGL, Mesa etc.. updated my computer and this morning did a fresh boot and noticed the messup of every single window's titlebar (see attached picture).

[image]

Parts of it became transparent, other parts seems to have loaded some distorted information from other parts of the screen or something.. real mess.

Some minutes ago arrived Nvidia update and xorg edgers updates too, installed them rebooted, titlebars still messed up.

I am on Asus n550jv laptop, Nvidia Geforce 750M, Running Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, latest bumblebee and nvidia 331.49 drivers.

Any ideas what to do to fix the glitch?
Thanks
Maris

Comment: I'm having this exact problem too. No amount of removing/re-installing drivers is changing this weird behavior

Comment: I've ended up with full reinstall of the system, this time i've managed to install my Nvidia GT 750M without bumblebee.

Answer (score 1):

I have ASUS N550JV as well and I was facing exactly same problem. I think some new updates released in xorg edgers ppa caused this issue. To fix this issue I have completely purged xorg edgers ppa and have also removed nvidia drivers. Window titlebars are appearing fine now. I will now try installing nvidia 319 from official repositories.

To reslve this issue first try purging xorg eders ppa using following commands:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

If that doesnt resolve the issue than try uninstalling nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

You can than install nvidia 319 drivers using instructions available here:
http://5thpeephole.blogspot.com/2013/10/install-ubuntu-1310-in-asus-n550jv.html

I think its best to avoid any such unofficial repositories for getting latest updates.

Edit: You can also check official bumblebee wiki page as well to get complete information about installing bumblebee and nvidia 319 update.

Comment: Thank you Arshad for your provided answer, meanwhile I already reinstalled my system and this time I managed to install my video card with nvidia-319, nvidia-prime and no bumblebee in the middle. Seems more stable and no hassle with "optirunning" every 3d app :)