# Window borders suddenly became transparent and ugly

Tags: unity

All of a sudden my window frames got really ugly and smudgy. I suspect it came from an update of Ubuntu, using 13.10 with the latest updates.

I would guess that unity is trying to make the window frames transparent and give me a delightful surprise, but instead I get this. I have tried turning off transparency in dconf-editor, but to no avail (it was off all along).

What to do?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot? You should be able to use http://imgur.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think I've ran into the same issue - please check my [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426603/messed-up-titlebars/427535?noredirect=1#427535) with the screenshot as well as provided possible scenario to resolve this.